# document.location.href not working in chrome or IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to redirect a page to after user clicks a alert button but its not working in javascript...

```
http://jsfiddle.net/wLDsE/2/
```

code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     alert('Go to google')
     document.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';

})
```

Comment: I don't see any click handler, you're redirecting on document ready

Comment: Have u tried it outside of JSfiddle? I.e. not in an IFRAME?

Comment: Try same domain (jsFiddler for example) instead of Google.

Comment: window.location does not work from jsfiddle...

Comment: Note that, outside of the frame, jsFiddle page works fine: http://fiddle.jshell.net/wLDsE/2/show/light/

Comment: Correct--it's a browser security feature.

Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://fiddle.jshell.net" from accessing a frame with origin "http://jsfiddle.net". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is specific to JSFiddle (and other demo websites which show the resulting code in a frame). These browsers prevent this behaviour inside frames, but it'll work fine in a plain old HTML page for you.

Comment: Actually, in this case it's Google using `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`, so loading a different page inside the frame works. But the principle's the same.

Comment: Im trying to do same with my website and have similar problem...Is there a work around...

Comment: @user1050619 A link to the code on your website would be useful, then!

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine, it is just jsFiddle wont redirect. You can see a working example of it at [this jsFiddle page](http://jsfiddle.net/wLDsE/2/show).

```
Note the /show to bring it onto a single webpage
```

Comment: It is the exact same code you had in your fiddle. It is just adding /show to the URL loads all your jsFiddle code in 1 page instead of the usual jsFiddle frames.

The point is, for me, your code works fine. You just cannot run it within the jsFiddle frames. I copied your code to my page. You can see it http://albuyeh.com/Testbed/Redirect.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can not redirect to a different domain. It against the role of

> Same Orign policy

You only redirect within same domain.